# Understanding lookahead in R regexp

Tags: r, regex

I'm trying to use multiple lookaheads to simulate an AND operator in R Perl-type regex with `grep`. However, I don't understand the output I am seeing. This is a sample code block

```
a <- c("abcxyz", "abcdef", "defxyz", "abcdefxyz", "xyzdefabc")
grep("(?<=abc)(?=xyz)", a, ignore.case=TRUE, perl=TRUE)  # returns 1
grep("(?=abc)(?=xyz)", a, ignore.case=TRUE, perl=TRUE)  # returns integer(0)
```

The second line suggests that the position in the string is between abc and xyz, and matches 'abcxyz'. Why does it not match 'abcdefxyz'?

On the third line, I am trying to output 1, 4 and 5, but it returns not found. Why is this happening?

I am using the alternative solution below but I would like to use lookaheads to deal with ordering when dealing with multiple lookaheads.

```
grep("abc.*xyz|xyz.*abc", a, ignore.case=TRUE, perl=TRUE)  # returns 1 4 5 as expected
```

Comment: In the second option, you used both `?=` instead of `?<=`.  Perhaps you need `grep("(?<=abc).*(?=xyz)", a, ignore.case=TRUE, perl=TRUE)`

Comment: @akrun I was trying to avoid using looking back and ahead together as it enforces an ordering, which I don't want. I've edited the example code to make it clearer. My expectation is from this example: http://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The `(?<=abc)(?=xyz)` regex only matches a location (place in string) that is between `abc` and `xyz`. It will find a match in `abcxyz` but won't find a match in `abcdefxyz` as the `xyz` does not immediately follow `abc`.

The `(?=abc)(?=xyz)` pattern will never match anything since it matches a location in a string that is followed with a 3-letter sequence that should be equal to `abc` and `xyz` at the same time, which is impossible.

What you are looking for is

```
^(?=.*abc)(?=.*xyz)
```

Or, to support multiple line input add the DOTALL modifier `(?s)` (so that `.` could match line breaks, too):

```
(?s)^(?=.*abc)(?=.*xyz)
```

These will match a string that has both `abc` and `xyz` in any order.

See [R demo](https://ideone.com/rb3oUt):

```
a <- c("abcxyz", "abcdef", "defxyz", "abcdefxyz", "xyzdefabc")
grep("^(?=.*abc)(?=.*xyz)", a, ignore.case=TRUE, perl=TRUE)
## => [1] 1 4 5
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I think I understand my source of confusion now. With `"(?=abc)(?=xyz)"`, the first portion sets the position to just before the occurrence of `abc`, and so the second portion cannot match to `xyz` at that position. Is this right?

Comment: The `(?=abc)` checks for a position befire `abc`, and once it is found, the regex engine tries to find `xyz` right at that very place (as `(?=...)` is a zero width assertion, it does not move the regex index when the lookahead pattern match is found). `abc` cannot be `xyz` thus, no match is found.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, happen to land here while looking up regex. Have a doubt, in regex, doesn't "^" mean starting location of a string? So shouldn't the regex try to find a pattern with 'abc' as the first three character sequence, but you say your regex will match 'abc' and 'xyz' in any order, so does that mean regex goes all the way till 'abc' in string 'xyzdefabc' finds 'abc' at the end, then comes back to starting point and finds 'xyz' ?

Comment: @KarthikS `^` matches the start of a string. My `^(?=.*abc)(?=.*xyz)` regex is matching a string containing both `abc` and `xyz` in any order, while the regex index remains at the start of string since lookaheads are non-consuming patterns. `.*abc` is checed for first, the match is found, the return value is *true* (meaning yes, go ahead and try atching the rest of the expression), then - still from the start of a string - the `.*xyz` is searched for. Since it is found and the return value is true the match succeeds,